# Convergence of a sequence to a $\sup$ in a signed measure space.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\nu)$ be a signed measure space such that $\nu(E)\in [-\infty, +\infty)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{A},$ and suppose $$\sup\{\nu(E)\;|\; E\in\mathcal{A}\}=+\infty.$$

1. Does there exist a sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(E_n)=+\infty$?
2. If so, can it be chosen such that moreover, $\nu(E_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

My attempt at answering question number 1.

We have for definition of infinity sup that $$\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\quad\exists E_m\in\mathcal{A}\quad\text{such that}\quad \nu(E_m)> m.\tag1$$
Let be $M>0$, then exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m>M$ and therefore from $(1)$ exists $E_m\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\nu(E_m)>M$. Thus we have proved that $$\forall M>0,\quad \nu(E_n)>M\quad \forall n\ge m$$ that is $\nu(E_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\ge m$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu(E_n)=+\infty$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauvalExcuse me. I edited by posting my solution to question number 1.

Comment: You also solved question 2. Note that it has nothing to do with measure theory. Simply: the sup of any nonempty $S\subset[-\infty,+\infty]$ is the limit of a sequence in $S.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties